# Auto session replay is not working when using @sentry/react

Tags: javascript, sentryreact

Auto session replay is not working. getting **Uncaught TypeError: e.recordDroppedEvent is not a function** error on console

I think the above error is causing an issue.. rest my code is
`Sentry.init({ dsn: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN, environment: process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT, replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1, replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1, integrations: [new BrowserTracing(), new Sentry.Replay()], tracesSampleRate: 0.33, });`

Comment: Tushar, have you looked at this issue? 
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/5451

Here they discuss some solutions. A person says that, in the specific case, the solution that fit best for him was to delete the tracesSampleRate in Sentry.init in sentry.client.config.js..